# How to append multiple input in list with input() function in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

[take input() with while loop and store in a specific list with append module. Can any solve this.I have tried many times but not get success.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpg97.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you taken the [tour] and read [ask] a good question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myList = []


while True:
  word = input("Enter a Word (Type 'q' to quit): ")
  if word == 'q':
    break
  myList.append(word)

print(myList)
```

**RESULT**

```
Enter a Word (Type 'q' to quit):  cat
Enter a Word (Type 'q' to quit):  dog
Enter a Word (Type 'q' to quit):  rat
Enter a Word (Type 'q' to quit):  q
['cat', 'dog', 'rat']
```